# Java error: char cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

Here is what the teacher asked me to do:

Enter a phone number (set up a string-type object for the phone number)
example:
(703) 323-3000

Display the phone number, using a format like the following:

Example 1:

The phone number you entered is 703-323-3000.

Display the content of the array that holds the count for each digit in the string.  Use a format similar to the following:

Example:
Digit 0 showed up 4 times.

Digit 1 showed up 0 times.

Digit 2 showed up 1 times.

Digit 3 showed up 4 times.

Digit 4 showed up 0 times.

Digit 5 showed up 0 times.

Digit 6 showed up 0 times.

Digit 7 showed up 1 times.

Digit 8 showed up 0 times.

Digit 9 showed up 0 times

The teacher also provided us with an algorithm as a hint:

set up an integer array of size 10
initialize each element to zero
input string of phone number
set SIZE = length of the string
set up a loop to iterate SIZE times
{
  get next character
  update array appropriately
  (for example: if the character is '7' then increment array[7] by 1.
 }

Display BOTH using appropriate messages:
    the original phone number
    contents of the array (using a loop).

Here is My code but it shows the error I mentioned when i use the equals() method, and displays a wrong answer if i use ==. Please Help.

```
public class Phones
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    int Num[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    String Phone = "703-323-3000";

    int SIZE = Phone.length() - 1;

    for(int count=0; count<= SIZE; count++)
    {
        for(int counter = 0; counter <= SIZE; counter++)
        {
            if(Phone.charAt(counter).equals(count))
            Num[count]++;
        }

        System.out.println("Digit " + count + " showed up " + Num[count] + " times");
    }





    }
}
```

This is my first time on this site, so sorry in advance if this is too long or incomprehensible. Thank you.

Comment: `charAt` returns a char not a String. So for starters, switch back to `==`. Step two is to debug from there :p Hint: you're comparing an int and a char.

Comment: There's a much simpler way to do this.  Get rid of the outer loop, and if `phone.charAt(counter)` turns out to be a digit, then just increment the array entry corresponding to its value.

Comment: A further tip for completing your assignment -- you're going to have to change the character you get to its numeric equivalent.  The digit from the string can be represented as a char, as a String, or as an int -- in order to reference one element of your array, you're going to need an int.

Comment: David Wallace, can you please elaborate on that. I kinda don't get it.

Comment: oh, i get what your talking about now keyser.

Comment: I don't know if your teacher explained this to you, but in order to learn Java you need to look up functions on the oracle API that can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api

Comment: arcy, I tried to typecast char to int. but I get the wrong number. I got a 51 instead of a 3 in one case

Comment: @jiija 51 is the ASCII value for the character 3. See the answers below.

Comment: @yshavit I get it now. In order for this to work I have to make sure that i'm comparing two things with the same data types. Thanks for the help; your a lifesaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the wrong answer with `==` is that you're comparing a char with an int incorrectly. In short, you're comparing `counter` with the unicode value of the characters, rather than with the number that the character represents.  (For "normal" characters like letters, numbers and simple punctuation, the unicode values are the same as the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/).)

The char `'0'` does *not* have an int value 0 -- it has the unicode value for the char `0`, which is [0x0030](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0030/index.htm) (aka 48 in base 10 -- the 0x format shows it in hex). By comparing the char the way you're doing, the first comparison will only be true if the char is the so-called "null char" 0x0000 (not to be confused with `null`, which is a null *reference*!), which won't happen for any sort of "normal" input.

Instead, you need a way to compare chars with ints. The easiest way to do this is to subtract the `'0'` char's value from the current char:

```
int charDistanceFromZero = Phone.charAt(counter) - '0';
```

If that distance is less than 0 or greater than 9, you have a char that's not a number. Otherwise, `charDistanceFromZero` is the offset you need into the array.

This works because the characters for the number digits start at 0 and are sequential from there. Try computing `charDistanceFromZero` for a few of them to get a feel for how it works out for getting the array index.

Answer (score 1):

`charAt` will return a value of type `char`, which is the reason why you cannot do `.equals(...)`.

Also, the characters representing the digits are in `['0' .. '9']`, which isn't the same as the interval `[0 .. 9]`. You need to translate the range by subtracting `'0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that `charAt` returns a `char`, which is a primitive type.  You need to have an object, not a primitive, in order to be able to call a method, such as `.equals`.  Moreover, when you tried to use `==` in place of `.equals`, you were comparing a `char` to an `int` value.  It's all right to do this, so long as you remember that the `int` value of a character is its encoded value, so 48 for `'0'`, 49 for `'1'` and so on.

To solve this problem, it's best to use the methods that come for free in Java's `Character` class; notably `isDigit`, which determines whether a character is a digit, and `getNumericValue`, which converts a character to the number that it represents.

It's also possible to dispense with the outer loop entirely, since once you've converted each digit character to its numeric value, you already have the index in the array that you want to increment.  So here is a much cleaner solution, that does not use nested loops at all.

```
public class Phones{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int counters[] = new int[10];
        String phone = "703-323-3000";

        for (char eachCharacter : phone.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isDigit(eachCharacter)) {
                int digit = Character.getNumericValue(eachCharacter);
                counters[digit]++;
            }
        }

        for(int digit = 0; digit < 10; digit++) {
            if (counters[digit] != 0) {
                System.out.format("Digit %d showed up %d times.%n", digit, counters[digit]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the first loop traverses your input string, incrementing the array index corresponding to each digit in the string.  The second loop just prints out the counts that it's found.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are fine... But to reduce ambiguity in code I generally just send the string into a char array before doing any control flows...  And as noted, 'Zero' is at [Unicode Code Point](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec&unicodeinhtml=dec) `48` so you need to subtract that value from the character index.

```
    char[] number =  "212-555-1212".toCharArray();

    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        // do something groovy with numbers[i] - 48    
    }
```

So for this solution you might do something like this....

```
    String phone = "212-555-1212".replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "" );
    int[] nums = new int[phone.length()];
    int[] queue = new int[phone.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = phone.toCharArray()[i] - 48;
        for(int num : nums) {
            if( nums[i] == num ) {
                queue[i] += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println( "Number: " + nums[i] + " Appeared: " + queue[i] + " times." );
    }
```